# The first day of spring/the first spring day

Tags: connotations

I guess, there is a subtle difference between these expressions:

> the first day of spring
>   the first spring day

Could you help me grasp it?

Comment: There are both correct. But the first day of spring is "prettier".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first day of Spring.

The first day of the season.

> The first spring day.

The first day in the season of Spring whose weather is what it would be on a normal spring day.

> Spring came officially a week ago. But because of the snow we've been
>   having this past week, today is the first spring day we've had. It has been wintry until today.

Comment: Not vice versa?

Comment: @Yulia Not really. "the first day of spring" usually refers to a specific calendar date (I think around March 20). "the first spring day " would be the first day (I suppose during springtime) that has spring-like weather.